# Regex.Replace: replace only first one found

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Regex search/replace only first occurrence in a string in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148518/how-to-regex-search-replace-only-first-occurrence-in-a-string-in-net)

How do I make Regex.Replace replace only the first found pattern?

Comment: Obviously marked as a duplicate but did not understand the question.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

What about `Regex.Replace ( String, String, Int32 )` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx)) ?

An example:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(str, replacement, 1); // The 1 makes the difference
```

Comment: what if you want to provide `count` parameter and `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` at the same time ? I cannot find any overload that fit.

Comment: @tigrou you provide options in the constructor `new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`, not in the `Replace` function.

Answer (score 4):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx

you can use `Regex.Replace(input, replacement, count);`

Comment: You cant. you need an instance because the overloads for the statics methods require a patter also. Sorry
This was nothing to do with the question.